# How to get the table result in my desired format MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi i'm working on a semester project i want a discuss a little problem over here i have a table try

```
mysql> select * from try;

+------+--------+
| name | course |
+------+--------+
| ali  | DB     |
| ali  | OOP    |
| ali  | DLD    |
| ali  | CS     |
| ali  | ODE    |
+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

here student is taking 5 courses i want to get the output in below format

```
+------+--------+
| name | course |
+------+--------+
| ali  | DB     |
|      | OOP    |
|      | DLD    |
|      | CS     |
|      | ODE    |
+------+--------+
```

tell me please if i'm able to do that or not if yes then what query should be passed because i have try many related to JOINS,GROUP by etc !! will be thankful for your help!! THANKS

Comment: Do that in your logic. SQL is designed for retrieving data.

Comment: kindly give me a direction or hint of query to get that desired output please!!

Comment: What format is this? Only first record has a value in name column? Same order?

Comment: actually i'm designing a JAVA APPLICATION Student Shedule system im connecting it through JDBC i just want to give student a view that he just only have a view of its courses and information so that's why i'm asking...if you have any other design or help to guide me to change or modify that table you can please!! @marcus adams

Comment: Then refer to the first comment. You're wasting time having MySQL format it like this. Just do `SELECT * FROM try` and format it in code using a loop.

Comment: oh thanks got thta idea :P

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(@temp != @temp:=A.name, A.name, '') AS name, A.course
FROM tableA AS A, (SELECT @temp:='') AS B
ORDER BY A.name
```

Comment: thanks got that working !! one more thing i wanna ask is that  when i have multiple students similarly repeating their name but courses are different  then what check i have to put there A.name='anystudent' or else??

Comment: @Ali That is upto you what is your requirement. You can put where condition to achieve that